# HttpWebRequest with response

Tags: vb.net

I want make an HttpWebRequest and get one response, this is my code.

```
Dim inStream As StreamReader
Dim webRequest As WebRequest
Dim webresponse As WebResponse 
Dim request As HttpWebRequest = webRequest.Create("https:/x.x.x")
request.CookieContainer = New CookieContainer
request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(login, "password")
Dim respone = request.GetResponse()
inStream = New StreamReader(respone.GetResponseStream())
TextBox1.Text = inStream.ReadToEnd
```

But I received 2 responses. One is okay but the second is without session. Can I filter the responses and get only one?

Comment: You receive two response messages, or you receive one response message containing a two-part body?

Comment: `NetworkCredentials` are only used in **Basic Authentication** or when there's a similar script server-side. Is this the case? You can receive a redirected response (the URI of the request is redirected to a new Location). Is this the case? What does it mean *without session*? `WebRequest/WebResponse` has no session. `Cookies` might contain session informations. A Server knows what to do with those.

Comment: i recived 2 messages

Comment: What do you mean by you received to messages?  Can you provide an example? If you need some tidied up code can provide that.  I have a few apps which pull API responses one I believe w/ HttpWebRequest